# HERE-maps Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, maps, here-api

I am building navigation app using HERE-Maps and [this Github](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/positioning) example, I replicated most of the code, I created new credentials for my app and followed steps written in documentation. But my code is crashing on `EngineInitializationCompleted` I think its because of some mistake I did in Manifest, Regarding Map Service or Disk cache.

**I am getting this error below:**

```
03-28 13:16:21.077 26352-26352/propelit.actionopps.com.propelit D/xxxxxx: Unknown error occurred.
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act={YOUR_INTENT_NAME} cmp=com.here.android.example.basicpositioningsolution/com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10205
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1395)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:623)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapServiceClient.a(MapServiceClient.java:77)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:621)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:363)
        at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:261)
        at com.nokia.maps.bw.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:132)
        at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.init(MapFragment.java:112)
        at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.initializeMapsAndPositioning(MainActivity.java:178)
        at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:369)
        at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.checkPermissions(MainActivity.java:350)
        at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
```

**My Manifest.xml :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="propelit.actionopps.com.propelit">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">


        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="skxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZO"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="Dgm_cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxv6FGEeQ"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="hZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZuC0m2vtXunxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5wZVsq1Li2RSU="/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="INTENT_NAME"
            android:value="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}" />
        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!--
            Embed the HERE Positioning Service.
            For more information, see the HERE SDK Developer's Guide
        -->
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.here.services.internal.LocationService" android:process=":remote">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My MainActivity:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPermissions();


    private void initializeMapsAndPositioning() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        rotateLoading = (RotateLoading) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawer, mTopToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        Window window = this.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this ,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
        mLocationInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLocationInfo);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(false);

        // Set path of isolated disk cache
        String diskCacheRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps";
        // Retrieve intent name from manifest
        String intentName = "";
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
            intentName = bundle.getString("INTENT_NAME");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Failed to find intent name, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean success = MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, intentName);
        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "diskcache", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Setting the isolated disk cache was not successful, please check if the path is valid and
            // ensure that it does not match the default location
            // (getExternalStorageDirectory()/.here-maps).
            // Also, ensure the provided intent name does not match the default intent name.
        } else {
            mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (error == Error.NONE) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "inside 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(61.497961, 23.763606, 0.0), Map.Animation.NONE);
                        map.setZoomLevel(map.getMaxZoomLevel() - 1);
                        map.addTransformListener(MainActivity.this);
                        mPositioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                        mHereLocation = LocationDataSourceHERE.getInstance(
                                new StatusListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onOfflineModeChanged(boolean offline) {
                                        // called when offline mode changes
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAirplaneModeEnabled() {
                                        // called when airplane mode is enabled
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onWifiScansDisabled() {
                                        // called when Wi-Fi scans are disabled
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onBluetoothDisabled() {
                                        // called when Bluetooth is disabled
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCellDisabled() {
                                        // called when Cell radios are switch off
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onGnssLocationDisabled() {
                                        // called when GPS positioning is disabled
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNetworkLocationDisabled() {
                                        // called when network positioning is disabled
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onServiceError(ServiceError serviceError) {
                                        // called on HERE service error
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPositioningError(PositioningError positioningError) {
                                        // called when positioning fails
                                    }
                                });
                        if (mHereLocation == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LocationDataSourceHERE.getInstance(): failed, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                        mPositioningManager.setDataSource(mHereLocation);
                        mPositioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(
                                MainActivity.this));
                        // start position updates, accepting GPS, network or indoor positions
                        if (mPositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR)) {
                            mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PositioningManager.start: failed, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("xxxxxx", error.getDetails());
                        Log.d("xxxxxx", error.getStackTrace());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onEngineInitializationCompleted: error: " + error + ", exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
// some more overriden methods and callback methods
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data
            android:name="INTENT_NAME"
            android:value="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}" />
        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Put your service name here

```
android:label="{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}"
android:value="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}"
action android:name="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}"
```

fill these places properly, you didn't mention activity and service names

Comment: I Tried to fill but no change , Additionally, This same code is working on the github example link i attached. I don't think so it is a problem it is just the name for the service, i can give any name